# Unable to validate a custom group using Knockout Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I cannot work out how to get the [Knockout Validation plugin](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) to validate a custom selection of viewmodel properties.  *I can call `isValid()` to validate the entire viewmodel successfully however.*

I have followed the documentation set out [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validating-Only-Specific-Observables) which covers the scenario and also checked all the answers I can find on stack overflow.

My code looks like this:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.myproperty = ko.observableArray().extend({ minLength: { message: 'You must specify at least one item.'} })
    self.anotherproperty = ko.observable().extend({ required: { params: true, message: 'You must supply a value.'} });

    self.IsEntireModelValid = function() {
         if (!self.isValid()) {
               self.errors.showAllMessages();
               return false;
         }
         else {
              return true;
    }

    self.IsAnotherPropertyValidOnly = function() {
         var errors = ko.validation.group(self.anotherproperty);
         if (errors.length > 0) {
            errors.showAllMessages();
            return false;
         } 
         else {
            return true;
         }
    }
```

When I call `self.IsAnotherPropertyValidOnly()` the errors variable contains no errors, but when I call `self.IsEntireModelValid()` I get the correct response.

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `errors().length`.

```
self.IsAnotherPropertyValidOnly = function() {
     var errors = ko.validation.group(self.anotherproperty);
     if (errors().length > 0) {
        errors.showAllMessages();
        return false;
     } 
     else {
        return true;
     }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WY7V3/2/

Comment: I thought that might be it as errors is indeed a function, but when I try it, knockout throws a "Maximum call stack size exceeded".  It sounds like there's a recursive loop somewhere else in my code?  However, your fiddle works perfectly.